# How to Zoom Out in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

Let's say I have One Emulator That is shown below. In that Emulator Right Side one Panel as we know that  it is control panel and Short Cut.Now In that panel one icon is for `Zoom`. When I click on that icon and `Zoom` something in My Emulator that work fine see below Image..

**Normal Screen :**

[image]

When press Zoom Button on Emulator..

[image]

**My Question :**  How to Zoom out in Emulator. Because there is no any Button. Everytime I wanna Shut Down Emulator and reopen it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a way to zoom out of the emulator screen. After you have zoomed in appropriately and want to zoom out (return to original state), simply *click the same zoom button again.*

If instead, you want to zoom out in stages like the way you zoomed in, *click the right mouse button.*

Comment: How to persist this zoom level? so that emulator screen always has this zoom level

Answer (score 3):

When you click on the zoom button you can also resize the window

Comment: Thanks, that was the only method that worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Pressing and holding the Cmd (Ctrl) key, and then zooming in/out using the mouse works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Holding `Ctrl` key while `left click` your mouse. For example, it works well while using google map.
Also, you can `double left` or `right click` to zoom in and `double left` or `right click` `+` `Ctrl` to zoom out.